# Displaying a progress dialog when upgrading database

Tags: android, database, progressdialog

The next version of my app needs to upgrade the database and this takes quite a bit of time. I'd like to show a progressDialog to update the user on the progress. Problem is, I can't quite figure out how and where to create the dialog.

My basic setup is that I have an activity which is essentially a splashscreen. It's on this screen I would like to show the progress. I have a separate DbAdapter.java file where a DatabaseHelper class extends SQLiteOpenHelper, where I override onUpgrade (the upgrade part is working fine).

I've tried a few different places to implement the progress dialog, but I don't seem to find the right spot. I tried passing context from my splashscreen activity to onUpgrade, but when onUpgrade runs it seems to be getting the context from my ContentProvider instead.

Does anyone have a good example of how to display a progress dialog when upgrading a database?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some code showing exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement an `AsyncTask`. Example:

```
class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //show your dialog here
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "title", "message", true, false)
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {        
        //update your DB - it will run in a different thread
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //hide your dialog here
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Then you just have to call

`new YourAsyncTask().execute();`

You can read more about AsyncTask here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I am actually using AsyncTask, called from onUpgrade in my DatabaseHelper, but wasn't creating the ProgressDialog inside it. I tried to implement it using your code above, but get this error using ProgressDialog.show:

The method show(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, boolean, boolean) in the type ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments (SpellDbAdapter.DatabaseHelper.upgradeTask, String, String, boolean, boolean)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: looking into it a little more, I believe the problem is that I have to create the dialog using the Activity context, in my case the splash screen activity, so using 'this' doesn't work. So... how do I do that? How do I get that activity from onUpgrade, which is called by SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: @anakin78z If your Activity is called XPTO instead of passing "this" in the AsyncTask, pass instead "XPTO.this"

Comment: Doesn't work. I think the issue is that the contentprovider is the context that opens the database when it performs onUpgrade. Since it's not an activity, the context doesn't allow for dialogs.

Comment: I had the exact need for this, glad I came upon this thread.  I was able to get it to work, following the approach that @pandre suggested, with some tweaks and improvements.  I was able to use the Context passed in to my SQLiteOpenHelper, however, it was from my Activity.  Would it work for you if you were to use the Context from your Content Provider and call ProgressDialog.show(cpContext.getApplicationContext(), .....); ?  I can post my working code as an answer if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog myProgressDialog = null;
public void DownloadFiles() {
        myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait !",
                "Updating...", true);
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                       //Your upgrade method !
                       YourUpdateFunction();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Error");
                }
                myProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }.start();
    }
```